# Java: The constructor gerbil(int) is undefined

Tags: java, object, constructor

So I've read over all of the constructor undefined posts on stackoverflow and tried the solutions and they haven't worked for me. Maybe I'm trying it wrong. I keep getting "the constructor Gerbil(int) is undefined."

The code that's the problem:

```
GerbilArray[i] = new Gerbil(i);
```

My full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Gerbil {

public String name;
public String id;
public String bite;
public String escape;

public Gerbil() {
    this.name = "";
    this.id = "";
    this.bite = "";
    this.escape = "";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many foods?");
    int totalFood = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("How many gerbils in the lab?");

    int numberOfGerbils = keyboard.nextInt();
    Gerbil[] GerbilArray = new Gerbil[numberOfGerbils];

    for(int i = 0; i <= numberOfGerbils; i++){
        GerbilArray[i] = new Gerbil(i);

        System.out.print("Lab ID:");
        String id = keyboard.next();

        System.out.print("Gerbil Nickname:");
        String name = keyboard.next();

        System.out.print("Bite?");
        String bite = keyboard.next();

        System.out.print("Escapes?");
        String city = keyboard.nextLine();

        for (int j = 0; j < totalFood; j++) {
            System.out.println("How many of food " + (j+1) + "do you eat?:");

        }

    }
}
}
```

Also you've probably seen that my nested for-loop isn't finished as well. I'm trying to make an array inside of an object that will store "x" amount of integers inside of my object listed from the user (int totalFood) but I have no idea how.

Comment: Change `GerbilArray[i] = new Gerbil(i)` to `GerbilArray[i] = new Gerbil()` because there is no `Gerbil(int data)` constructor.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the constructor problem!

Comment: Don't delete posts after they are answered, this is against the idea of Stack Overflow - maybe somebody having same problem as you can come here and find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a constructor `Gerbil(int a)` in the class `Gerbil` and you try to call it!

Just call it this way:

```
GerbilArray[i] = new Gerbil();
```

Comment: Thank you!! What does that do exactly? My class hasn't really gone over objects too much so far.

Comment: @newJavaUser> You're welcome. In order to create an object you should call it's constructor with the proper arguments. For example `Gerbil g = new Gerbil()`. (There are other ways that I don't want to confuse you know with them)